# Replacing several lines in a script with a single line using sed

Tags: sed

Say I have a script where I want to change several lines for a single line.

For example, I got a new function that can summarize several commands, so that I can replace in my script as follows:

Original

```
some_code
command1
command2
command3
some_more_code
```

Edited

```
some_code
foo()
some_more_code
```

How would you do that using sed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed '/some_code/,/command3/ !b
/some_code/ b
/command3/ a\
foo()
d' YourFile
```

- be carrefull about meta character ( like `&\\^$[]{}().`) in any of the pattern (except your foo() line)

Answer (score 1):

I am answering my own question here.

I couldn't figure out a way to do it in one go, so I split the problem into two parts.

Part 1: replace the first line

```
sed -e 's/command1/foo()/g' file1 > file2
```

Part 2: remove the rest of the lines

```
sed -e '/command2/,+1d/' file2 > file3
```

I'd prefer a more elegant way though, where I can be flexible in the number of lines that I am replacing, possibly matching the last command in the block. Any ideas?

Comment: Well, for starters you could handle those two commands in the same sed call, i.e., `sed 's/command1/foo()/; /command2/,+1d' file1 > file2`. I'm not entirely sure that this approach isn't too brittle, though. Are you perhaps looking to replace multi-line regexes?

Comment: well it may work for your needs but if your command sequence was `cmd1;cmd2;cmdX;cmd3` your two lines will destroy your script. Your script works only for cmds1-3 are continuous. You can also check this pattern with awk. One can do multiple line matching with awk.

Comment: idea - use the right tool for the job. sed is line-oriented and as such is for simple substitutions on individual lines, it is NOT for anything involving multiple lines. Just use awk, it was made for stuff like this.

Comment: I see that sed might not be the best tool for the job, but it can work nevertheless.

Answer (score 1):

Just use awk:

```
$ awk -v RS='^$' -v ORS= '{sub(/command1\ncommand2\ncommand3/,"foo()")}1' file
some_code
foo()
some_more_code
```

The above uses GNU awk for multi-char RS.

Comment: That works alright! Thx. I am nevertheless going for the sed version of @NeronLeVelu.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/command1/,/command3/c\foo()' file
```